# Label not visible on Panel when calling visible = true

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I already tried google to find an answer to my problem but haven't found a solution.

I working with C# and WinForms. I created a panel and added a label to it. This panel is set to `myPanel.Visible = false`at first. I want to set it  `myPanel.Visible = true` when I click a button. The button is calling a function. During the function call I want to show a progessbar in the panel, so I set this `myPanel.Visible = true`and at the end of the function I set it back to `myPanel.Visible = false`.

The problem is, that the label isn't visible.

When I don't set `myPanel.Visible = false` at the end of the function, the label is visible, but only at the end of the function.

I also tried to programmatically add the label in the function called, still not working. The second idea I tried was to use `this.PerformLayout();` during the call of the function.

It seems like that the application is drawing the label only at the end of the function call, but I need it to be drawn during the function is called.

Thanks for any help.

```cs
        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Adding label to panel
            MyLabel label = new MyLabel();
            label.Text = "Test";
            label.Location = new Point(0, 0);

            progressPanel.Controls.Add(label);

            //Showing progressPanel
            progressPanel.Visible = true;

            progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
            progressBar1.Value = 1;
            progressBar1.Step = 1;

            //Some Code

            progressPanel.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: post your code...

Comment: So you have a label in a panel, and when you hide the panel, the label isn't visible? I'm not sure what else you would expect. Perhaps you want to add the label directly to the form?

Comment: Your method is probably blocking the UI thread, so `myPanel.Visible = true` cannot resolve until your function returns. A call to `Application.DoEvents()` would solve the symptoms of the problem, but the reality is if you're doing a background operation, you should never block the UI thread.

Comment: Think of a panel like a bucket, and your label is a sponge. You put your sponge in the bucket and show people.  Now you put the bucket behind a wall, you can no longer see the sponge in the bucket now. (Assuming this is what is going on in your code.)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're expecting. Note that every control in your panel will not be visible when you set the `Visible` property of your panel to `false`.

Comment: This is pretty fundamental, controls only get painted when the UI thread isn't busy executing code.  It can do only one thing at a time.  Expensive code that hangs the UI thread should be moved into a worker thread.  Fall in the pit of success with the BackgroundWorker class, you can hide the panel again with its RunWorkerCompleted event.

Comment: @HansPassant: Indeed. I felt a bit dirty for even mentioning `Application.DoEvents()` as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you see is normal.  The changes in visibility only take effect when the UI thread gets a chance to repaint your window.  But, while you function is running, the UI thread is busy, so it can't repaint your window.  The UI thread only frees up at the end of your function call, so that's when the component's visibility changes take effect.

What you need to do is to perform your function's work on a different thread so that the UI thread is free to repaint your window while the function is still running.

One way to do this, is by using [Task.Run()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) combined with the [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) keywords.  Here is a basic example of how this could look like, using the code you posted:

```
async private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ....

    //Showing progressPanel
    progressPanel.Visible = true;

    progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
    progressBar1.Value = 1;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;

    // this work will happen on separate thread,
    // so the UI thread will be free to update the panel visibility
    Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(percentage => progressBar1.Value = percentage);
    await Task.Run(() => this.WorkToBePerformedOnSeparateThread(progress));

    progressPanel.Visible = false;
}

private void WorkToBePerformedOnSeparateThread(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    // do work...
    progress.Report(25); // Report 25% completed...

    // do more work

    progress.Report(50); // Report 50% completed...

    // more work

    progress.Report(75); // Report 75% completed...

    // etc...
}
```

As pointed out by Rene in the comments, just remember that you can only do UI work on the UI thread.  So, in the example above, you'll notice that the progress reporting is performed through the [Progress<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class which allows you to change the progress bar value (UI work) from the separate thread, because it takes care of ensuring that the progress reporting happens on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, using `async/await` may be the better solution than my background worker suggestion. But remember to use `Invoke` for updating the progress bar, because accessing the UI from another thread is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Rene: I would personally use the `IProgress<T>` class to handle progress updates.  But, yes, it's good that you point this out.  UI components should not be manipulated on a non-UI thread.

Comment: Thanks introducing `IProgress<T>` to me. I didn't get the chance to use .NET 4.5 so much yet, so I'm constantly suprised what cool features there are now.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and answers! The progressbar is working and all labels are visible now! I used the solution of sstan.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is obviously that you are performing your task in the UI thread. So the UI itself doesn't get repainted while this task is working. And when you finished, it's still invisible.

Try using a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead. Use its `ProgressChanged` event to update your progress bar.

If you show some code, I can go into details of implementation.

**UPDATE:**

I actually prefer sstan's answer, but I promised to show the `BackgroundWorker` way. It may still be helpful if for some reason you cannot use `async/await`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += DoWork;
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerCompleted;
        _backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += WorkerProgressed;
    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Adding label to panel
        MyLabel label = new MyLabel();
        label.Text = "Test";
        label.Location = new Point(0, 0);

        progressPanel.Controls.Add(label);

        //Showing progressPanel
        progressPanel.Visible = true;

        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;

        // to avoid multiple starts
        buttonAdd.Enabled = false;

        // start working
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();        
    }
    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(1);

        // work

        _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(50);

        // more work

        _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100);
    }
    private void WorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressPanel.Visible = false;
        buttonAdd.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void WorkerProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

So as you see, `BackgroundWorker`s are fairly easy to use, but `async/await` is even easier since you don't have to write so much code just for parallelization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used sstan's solution with async.